# How can I use keyup events with JQuery-ui draggable elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, keyup, jquery-events

I have a page with multiple elements which are made draggable via JQuery-ui.

I want to make it so that when the user clicks on one of these elements, and presses any key, another function will be called for further processing (and checking the keycode)

Given the HTML:

```
<div id="drag-el" class="drsel"> </div>
```

If I use the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.drsel').each(function() {
        $(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
            alert("Keyup event");
        });
    });
});
```

Then the event will never ever fire.

Instead I have to use the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup', 'body, .drsel', function() {
        alert("Keyup event");
    });
});
```

However, in this case the event will only fire if the user clicks the main body (i.e. not the draggable element), then clicks the element, then presses a key.

Another issue is that the event will then fire if the user presses a key when focus is on the document body, but the event will never fire if 'body' is not included in the selector.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhobd21k/1/) that you can play around with.

Is there a way around this? I even went so far as to add

```
$(document.body).focus();
```

to the ready function, but found that only works for the first time the page loads - if the page reloads, then that solution no longer helps.

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly, obviously, if you want that keyup event is firing, the focus must be always in the element that have the event attached, otherwise it doesn't fire. But the fiddle you share is working fine. Just make focus in the frame of the result and press some key. And again. And again. Works the 3 times.

Comment: That is a complication due to the nature of the jsfiddle site, it seems, as going into the page fresh and clicking on the draggable element keeps focus in the javascript pane.

As such, it would seem that the issue is really that clicking on a draggable element doesn't make it the focus.

Comment: Yeah, you can workaround with something like `$(element).on('click', this.focus())`

Comment: That also doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/mhobd21k/2/ - the click event never fires on that draggable element.

Comment: You are wrong. Click event fires: https://jsfiddle.net/mhobd21k/3/

Comment: The behaviour is very inconsistent - I checked in Chrome, Firefox, IE Edge, IE11, IE10, and IE9, but in all cases the click event would not fire until I double-clicked.

Then, suddenly, it started working on single clicks, too.

However, in all cases, the focus never changed.

The only exception to that was IE11, where the focus would change, however the click event would not fire except for double clicks.

Comment: Maybe you need another plugin. jQuery UI is fine, but it's not the better. To this purposes I always use Draggabilly, it's the best plugin i've found for this. http://draggabilly.desandro.com/ Try it. Easy to use and ready to use.

Comment: I apologise for my difficulty - this problem has been frustrating for me.     Whilst I was getting odd behaviour via jsfiddle, implementing the click event in the form you described (though, wrapped in another function(){}) on the website where I was experiencing the issue appears to have resolved it.      If you would like to put that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: In my case, jsfiddle works fine with the click event. I don't know what's the issue, but I will go to put an answer, maybe it helps also to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we said in comments, you can workaround the issue of the focus element with a click or mousedown event:

https://jsfiddle.net/mhobd21k/3/

```
  $('.drsel').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).focus();
  });
```

OR

```
  $('.drsel').on('mousedown', function(e){
    $(this).focus();
  });
```